# When does paypal process first recurring payment after a recurring payment profile is created?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am creating a subscription based website using PHP and I successfully managed to create recurring payment profile using Paypal Merchant SDK.

When I test the checkout in sandbox mode it returns to success url and I get IPN for **recurring_payment_profile_created**.

But I don't get any IPN for **recurring_payment**. Maybe I don't know when does Paypal process first payment after the profile is created, please let me know if that's the case.

Please share your experience with recurring payments, I searched already but couldn't find any related answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recurring_payment` IPN will be received when you receive your first payment.
The first payment date is based on the `PROFILESTARTDATE` of the profile that you set when you perform `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`API request.

Comment: I can't find any reference for PROFILESTARTDATE . Can you show me some example of PROFILESTARTDATE with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileAPI request?

Comment: Did you check the documentation:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/